# Getting DOM attributes of elements selected in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I'm building a proof of concept test with CasperJS and I'm trying to wrap my head around when things are available and when they are not.

I'm a bit fuzzy on why `evaluate()` is required and why one cannot just get a page and go to town with `document.querySelectorAll()`, but that ends up giving me a nodeList with a length of zero... even after `casper.echo`ing out the HTML and SEEING plenty of matching selectors.

Right now, I'm trying this:

```js
var tile;
var pid;        
casper.waitForSelector('.m-product-tile', function() {
    tile = this.evaluate(function() {
        return  __utils__.findOne('.m-product-tile');
    });
    pid = this.evaluate(function() 
        return __utils__.findOne('.m-product-tile').getAttribute('data-pid');
    });
    //do cools stuff like click() on tile and make sure the URL has the pid in it
});
```

But this feels wrong as I am not sure `__utils__.findOne()` will always return the same element.

I'd love to be able to do this instead:

```js
pid = tile.getAttribute('data-pid');
```

But when I attempt that, I get an error:

```
uncaughtError: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'tile.getAttribute('data-pid')')
```

Did `tile` somehow cease to be a `DOMNode` with a `getAttributes` method? Using `typeof tile`, it still thinks it's an object. I echoed out the DOMNode and it has a `getAttributes` key.

The code in the first example DOES work with `getAttribute`... so why does `tile` morph into something that no longer has a `getAttributes` method?

http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate provides a pretty good answer... but still, I'd like to know why, if what the page is passing back, is a `DOMNode`, why can't I treat it like one?

Comment: Such an existential question. It's just the way phantomjs and its `evaluate` function work. You cannot pass non-primitives: functions will be stripped, because they are objects that where created with `new`.

Comment: Why not just use  `pid = this.getElementAttribute('.m-product-tile','data-pid');` ?

Comment: I have several elements with that class, I'd need to be assured I was referring to the same one returned by the findOne() method. What I have right now does work, but it feels wrong to query the remote DOM twice and hope it returns the same element.

Comment: Artjom B: Thank you for your knowledge. I'll continue the way I'm doing it now.

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own question.